# Multiple inheritance: 2Classes1Method

Tags: c++

I've just tried this piece of code:

```
struct FaceOfPast
{
    virtual void Smile() = 0;
};

struct FaceOfFuture
{
    virtual void Smile() = 0;
};

struct Janus : public FaceOfPast, public FaceOfFuture
{
    virtual void Smile() {printf(":) ");}
};
```

...

```
void main()
{
    Janus* j = new Janus();
    FaceOfFuture* future = j;
    FaceOfPast* past = j;

    future->Smile();
    past->Smile();

    delete j;
}
```

It works as intended (outputs two smiley faces), but I don't think it should even compile, redeclaration of `Smile()` in `Janus` being ambiguous.

How (and why) does it work?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There's no ambiguity because you call `Smile()` on pointers to `FaceOfFuture` and `FaceOfPast` that only declare one method `Smile()`.

**Because calling the method on a base class pointer can't result in an ambiguity, let's treat the situations when you call the method directly on the child class pointer**:

```
Janus* j = new Janus();
j->Smile();
```

The derived class, besides overriding, also hides the base classes' declaration of `Smile()`. You'd have an ambiguity only if you wouldn't be overriding the method in your derived class:

The following compiles:

```
struct FaceOfPast
{
    virtual void Smile() {printf(":) ");}
};
struct FaceOfFuture
{
    virtual void Smile() {printf(":) ");}
};
struct Janus : public FaceOfPast, public FaceOfFuture
{
   virtual void Smile() {printf(":) ");}
};
int main()
{
   Janus* j = new Janus();
   j->Smile();
}
```

Although you call `Smile` on a `Janus`, the base class declarations are hidden.

The following doesn't:

```
struct FaceOfPast
{
    virtual void Smile() {printf(":) ");}
};

struct FaceOfFuture
{
    virtual void Smile() {printf(":) ");}
};

struct Janus : public FaceOfPast, public FaceOfFuture
{
};

int main()
{
   Janus* j = new Janus();
   j->Smile();
}
```

Because of the ambiguity.

Comment: The question doesn't seem to be about the calling part, but the redefining part: why can you redefine 2 virtual methods with the same name from 2 different classes by only writing a single method ?

Answer (score 1):

According the C++ standard (10.3.2):

> If a virtual member function vf is declared in a class **Base** and in a class **Derived**, derived directly or indirectly from **Base**, a member function **vf** with the same name, parameter-type-list, cv-qualification, and ref-qualifier (or absence of same) as **Base::vf** is declared, then **Derived::vf** [...] overrides **Base::vf**.

There doesn't seem to be any special treatment for multiple inheritance, so it most probably apply here too: `void Janus::Smile()` overrides both methods without any ambiguity, just because it has the exact same name and signature as both base class methods.

Answer (score 0):

```
Janus* j = new Janus();
FaceOfFuture* future = j;
FaceOfPast* past = j;
```

This section of code casts down to the to a base class. So when you do the following

```
future->Smile();
past->Smile();
```

This is actual a pointer to a FaceofPast and FaceOfFuture.